# Passing variables to a bash script with default values

Tags: bash, shell

I currently have a bash script in which I have hard coded certain variables, and I was hoping to be able to set these variables by passing arguments.

A simple example: consider the script `example.sh` where I have hard coded values for the variables `data_names` and `run_this`

```
#!/bin/bash

data_names=("apple_picking" "iris")
run_this="TRUE"    

#remainder of script runs things using these hard coded variables
```

I am wondering if it is possible to edit this script so that:

1. I can set the values of `data_names` and `run_this` by passing arguments when I run `bash example.sh`
2. If no arguments are passed for either `data_names` and `run_this` to the script, then the variables should take on default (hard coded) values.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far and what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something robust, clear & elegant, you should take a look to `getopts` to set `run_this`

Tutorial: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial Examples: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035

I think of something like :

```
./script --run-this=true "apple_picking" "iris"
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This is the best option by far since it doesn't require input arguments to be specified in a given order / can handle multiple input arguments.

Comment: Sure, that's the goal of the proposed solution HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create a BASH array using passed arguments
data_names=("$@")

# if array is empty assign hard coded values
[[ ${#data_names[@]} -eq 0 ]] && data_names=("apple_picking" "iris")

# print argument array or do something else
printf "%s\n" "${data_names[@]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is like this:

```
  run_this=${1:-TRUE}
  IFS=',' read -a data_names <<< "${2:-apple_picking,iris}"
```

Assuming your script is called like:

```
 ./script.sh first_argument array,values,in,second,argument
```